# Global variables in python flask web application

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

I have implemented a web server using python flask and hosted in pythonanywhere.com ...
I have used global variables in my implementation for handle login sessions. 
for example-

```
TOKENS = {"OAUTH_TOKEN": ""}
if(TOKENS['OAUTH_TOKEN']) == "":
   authorized = Flase
else:
   authorized = True
```

But the problem is when a user logged and authorized the second user get as a authorized user. pythonanywhere used WSGI as a server for run python flask web application. How can I handle each user as separates threads?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write your code to create a login solotion but It's not realy safe.need to set the login credential in the session and load the user with each request and load it in each request and set g object.

```
#login
session['user'] = user_id


@app.before_request
def before_request():
    current_user = user_obj
    g.user = current_user
```

You can use [this guide](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins) for a good login app.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/.) extension.
It can handle most of typical user-management activities out-of-the-box.